# My SQL c# Performance issue

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am migrating my web application from `c# SQL` to `c# MySQL`

I am comparing MySQL vs SQL performance.

I have a table with about 200K rows.

> Select * query from SQLyog for MYSQL is much faster than 
>   Select * query from SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server
>
> On the other hand accessing MySQL table from c# code using MySQL Connector.C >6.1 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; is 2 to 3 times slower than accessing SQL >table from c# using `System.Data.SqlClient;`

Environment 64 bit Windows development machine running Connectior 6.1 which is 32 bit.

Is connectior being 32 bit is an issue ?

Can I use something else for c# mysql access that gives me equal or better performance than c# sql

How `SQLyog` is able to achieve better performance ?

Comment: Can you show the select-code of both?

Comment: Select 'multiple columns' from tablename the query is very simple in both mysql and sql

Comment: do you use in both cases the SqlDataReader / MySqlDataReader? That should be the fastest aproach in C#.

Comment: Yes I user respectively SqlDataReader and MySqlDataReader